# Error while defining an angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, undefined, angularjs-controller

I have an view (insight index.html) like that:

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
[...]
    <div>{{status}} </div>
</body>
```

I start the App onDeviceReady:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document);
});
```

I have this module:

```
var mainAppModul = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute'])
         .config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

       $routeProvider
         .when('/', {
         controller: MainCtrl,
         template: '<h1> Main View {{ status }} </h1>'        
         });
       $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist (/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
    });
```

As far as I know, there are different ways to define a controller. One way is like that:

```
mainAppModul.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope)
 {
    $scope.status = "It works!";
}]);
```

The other one is like this:

```
function MainCtrl ($scope) 
{
   $scope.status = "It works!";
}
```

While the 1st Version results in `[ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl ' is not a function, got undefined`, the 2nd Version works fine.

Is there something I misunderstood in general?

Answer (score 1):

`ngRoute` works in combination with `ngView`  You won't need to specify the `ng-controller` in your templates, `ngRoute` takes care of that for you. When you have this:

```
var mainAppModul = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            // controller: MainCtrl, // EDIT: needs to be a string of the controller name
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            template: '<h1> Main View {{ status }} </h1>'
        });
});
```

All you need is this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body>
        <ng-view></ngview>
    </body>
</html>
```

`ngRoute` will put the template of the specified route into `ng-view` and use the associated controller.

**Note:** `ngRoute` does not come with angular.js, you'll need the angular-route.js included as well.

Comment: I have ngRoute installed. I'm not sure, if your answer fits my question, because (i think) the route is not the problem.
2nd thing: `ng-app="myApp"` bootstraps my app, right? So this would be in conflict with 
`angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document);
});`
But if I can't add `ng-app` on html-tag, so how can I connect the view with the controller? Shouldn't be there an `ng-controller="MainCtrl"`??

Comment: The route defines the controller to use, when it inserts the html fragment into `ng-view`  You can define other controllers within your template but the controller defined in the route will be the parent controller.  The way you defined your controller with `mainAppModul.controller` should be fine.

Comment: I just noticed this, the `controller` property of a route needs to be the string name of the controller you want to use. so it should be `controller: 'MainCtrl'`

Comment: With regards to your question of using `angular.bootstrap(document);` I've never had to use that in order to get angular running properly with `ng-app` in the `<HTML>` tag